# Switch to Ejabberd login

Tags: ejabberd

While switching to ejabberd user in ubuntu requesting password.

To avoid this using sudo. But instead of switching to ejabberd user, switching to the particular installation folder.

ejabberdctl command also not working in that location.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you have ejabberd 21.01 installed using Ubuntu package. Looking at https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/ejabberd/filelist I see that ejabberdctl is installed in

```
/usr/sbin/ejabberdctl
```

Does that file exist? What permissions does it have? If you provide the full path, can you execute it using "ejabberd" user? And using "root"?